# Knockout Binding with Virtual Elements Not Working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding, bindinghandlers

I'm working on some custom bindings, and in one I'd like to be able to show a table from some arrays of strings.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brigand/3R8ck/)

I simplified it down to this custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.table = {
    init: function tableBinding(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        element.innerHTML = tableTemplate;

        var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(valueAccessor());

        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);

        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
    }
};
```

This is the contents of template:

```
<!-- if: head && head.length -->
<thead>
<tr data-bind="foreach: head">
    <th data-bind="text: $rawData">not working th</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<!-- /ko -->

<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
<tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <td data-bind="text: $data">not working td</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And some example data.

```
ko.applyBindings({
    table: {
        head: ["Name", "Position"],
        rows: [
            ["John", "Janitor"],
            ["Mike", "IT"],
            ["Paul", "HR"],
            ["Rick", "Coffee Fetcher"]
        ]
    }
});
```

I'm using Knockout 3.0, however anything that'd work on Knockout 2.x would also work here.  If you look at the fiddle, the `<thead>` part is displaying properly, but the bindings for the body aren't.  It works fine if I inline the template, and use a `with` binding, as in, `with: table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to confess, at the moment I am not following all you are doing here, but I can tell enough that your example will work if your `if` statement uses `ko if:` instead of just `if:`.

http://jsfiddle.net/AhLzS/1/

So instead of this:

```
<!-- if: head && head.length -->
```

go with this:

```
<!-- ko if: head && head.length -->
```

The containerless binding syntax requires `<!-- ko ... --> ... <!-- /ko -->` as the virtual container. Thus if an html comment syntax just has `<!-- if ... -->`, knockout does not do anything special.

From the knockout documentation for the "if" binding:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

> The `<!-- ko -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` comments act as start/end markers,
>   defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout
>   understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real
>   container element.

Comment: Thank you!  No idea why that'd cause the problem, but it does fix it :-)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - answer updated with note about knockout's "containerless flow syntax".

Comment: Yeah, it appears the `<!-- /ko -->` was causing problems because it couldn't find the opening comment tag.  Thanks :-)